# Why is there a different font thickness if compiling differently?

Tags: compiling, dvi

I've noticed that the text looks different if I compile a file via `latex,dvipdf` or via `pdflatex`, for example, consider this `.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Prueba de texto para comparar compilaciones tex$\rightarrow$dvi$\rightarrow$pdf, y tex$\rightarrow$pdf, via latex dvipdf y pdflatex respectivamente.

\[ 1234567890-+\times \]
\end{document}
```

The outputs that are produced by the previous two compiling paths look like in the image:

[image]

The above is what's produced by making the intermediate `dvi` file. The thickness is bigger in this case.

I would like to know the reason for this, and I would like to know how to get the same effect when compiling with `pdflatex`.

In view of the comments, this is the output of pdfinfo for the latex-dvipdf file:

```
Title:          grosor.dvi
Creator:        dvips(k) 5.993 Copyright 2013 Radical Eye Software
Producer:       GPL Ghostscript 9.10
CreationDate:   Sat Jul 11 23:44:25 2015
ModDate:        Sat Jul 11 23:44:25 2015
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595 x 842 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      11577 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.4
```

and for the pdflatex file:

```
Creator:        TeX
Producer:       pdfTeX-1.40.14
CreationDate:   Sat Jul 11 23:44:30 2015
ModDate:        Sat Jul 11 23:44:30 2015
Tagged:         no
Form:           none
Pages:          1
Encrypted:      no
Page size:      595.276 x 841.89 pts (A4)
Page rot:       0
File size:      36096 bytes
Optimized:      no
PDF version:    1.5
```

There is a difference in the PDF version.

And this is the difference of the output of `pdffonts`: for the dvi->pdf file:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XDBXOD+CMBX10                        Type 1C           WinAnsi          yes yes no      12  0
KGXOBL+CMSY10                        Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no      10  0
FJRNGQ+CMR10                         Type 1C           Custom           yes yes no       8  0
```

and for the pdflatex file:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
TPACRM+CMR10                         Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       4  0
NIWPOC+CMSY10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       5  0
JEQXNS+CMBX10                        Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no       6  0
```

Comment: On my machine, I don't get this difference at all. Maybe just your PDF viewer?

Comment: Can you zoom in on a word and post the result?

Comment: If it is a true difference, consider checking the respective files with `pdfinfo`.

Comment: @cfr May I ask which of my two results are you getting (at least cloer to it?

Comment: @jon  There is a difference in the pdf version. Is this the latest? Or any reason for dvipdf producing a pdf with an older version?

Comment: Neither really. Maybe closer to the second but much clearer and better defined. (Might just be the screenshot, though.)

Comment: You can put `\pdfminorversion=4` as the first line in your `.tex` document to test when compiling with pdfTeX.

Comment: Your question says "dvipdf", your output dvips. How do you compile? And did you check the fonts used (e.g. with the adobe reader->document properties).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm compiling in the way stated in the question. That's just the output of pdfinfo. latex -> dvipdf.

Comment: @cfr It's a very small screenshot just to show the difference, that's why it's so badly defined. Could I ask what PDF version are you producing?

Comment: Oops, I meant `pdffonts`.

Comment: @jon I added the outputs to the question, and there are differences, I don't really understand them though.

Comment: The PDF I get using `dvipdf` is version 1.5, by the way. And I do not get the first line in the fonts listing. With pdfTeX, I do not get the third line of your font listing.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `dvipdf` is just a wrapper for `dvips` as far as I know. At least, it is on my machine.

Comment: Your mwe doesn't use CMBX10. The output of pdffonts imho can't be from this example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Well... it is.

Comment: Compile your example above and then put the pdf's and the log-file of the pdflatex compilation somewhere on the net.

Comment: Without the TeX logs we can't help here: this looks very much like an issue with your set up.

Comment: Answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex/337122#337122).