# Thicker font in latex + dvipdf versus pdflatex (TeXLive 2015)

Tags: texlive

Reviving a four year old unanswered question: [Why is there a different font thickness if compiling differently?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/254913)

This time providing the output pdf files:

- [latex+dvipdf version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VqBsXEWLhfeUtvQmI5dzNLS00/view?usp=sharing)
- [pdflatex version](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7VqBsXEWLhfRGxRQnd0cnlNRVk/view?usp=sharing)

Not only font thickness, but microtypography is also different. You'd be able to notice if you open both documents in "maximized" mode, and switch back and forth between the pdfs very quickly (e.g., with Alt-Tab or something similar, I'm using i3wm so it's very easy for me). As an example, in the second word 'ipsum', 'u' is closer to 's' in latex, but closer to 'm' in pdflatex.

How to fix this, i.e., have consistent look of the document?

Since I like the thicker text but use pdflatex for my work, how to reproduce the thicker text in pdflatex?

EDIT 1: So I noticed the thickness is not visible in google pdf viewer, but it's visible in both evince, and zathura pdf viewers. I haven't tested adobe acrobat though.

Comment: TeX and LaTeX were designed for putting ink on paper, so the most valid test of the system is how it looks when printed. Otherwise it is probably an issue of the combination of PDF viewer, operating system, and screen.

Comment: This is just a pointer to an existing question which was active 10 days ago. This is a duplicate, even if it cannot be closed as such.

Comment: Answered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305258/xelatex-font-rendering-tend-to-be-slightly-bolder-compared-to-pdflatex/337122#337122).